# How do you prove that if a set is countably infinite, then there exists a bijection between from the natural numbers to the set?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

A homework question asks the following:

"Let $X$ be a countable, not finite set. Show that there is a bijection $\phi :\mathbb{N}\to X$."

I was under the impression that this is the definition of what it means for a set to be countable and not finite (i.e. "countably infinite"). Then is this a trivial proof, or is it not the true definition and instead the result of a more subtle axiom?

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411351/if-a-set-is-countable-and-infinite-there-is-a-bijection-between-the-set-and-m), but it involves constructing a bijection *from* $X$ *to* $\mathbb{N}$ rather than from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$.

Comment: What is the definition of countable? And what is the definition of finite?

Comment: A bijection is a bijection in either direction.

Comment: You're absolutely right OP. Unless you have a different definition to work with, that is the usual definition of countably infinite.

Comment: Context matters. Presumably you are expected to know the definition of countable which lies behind that particular homework problem. My guess will be that this is not exactly the definition, *in that context*.

Comment: When in doubt, look it up ... and I mean in your textbook or course notes, not on some random site on the Internet. Not even here.

Comment: Just want to clarify and second @DavidK's comment. The definition you have in mind is an accepted definition, but odds are it's not the definition you're working with, or it wouldn't be a homework problem.

Comment: @mjqxxxx So if I want to show that there exists a bijection from A to B, it is sufficient to show that there is a bijection from B to A? It makes intuitive sense, but is it rigorous?

Comment: Absolutely. Any bijection comes with a natural inverse bijection. If $\phi : A \to B$ is a bijection, let $\psi : B \to A$ be given by $\psi(\phi(b)) = b$. I leave it to you to check well-definedness, injectivity, and surjectivity.

Comment: @SamuelErens It's not entirely trivial to conclude that a bijection has an inverse, and the inverse is itself a bijection. By "not entirely trivial", I mean there is a proof to do there, even though it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: At the risk of this comment section becoming too long, I should point out that a set $A$ is sometimes defined to be countable if there exists an enumeration (possibly finite) $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ of the elements of $A$. The exercise would then be to show that the existence of an infinite enumeration is nothing but the existence of such a bijection.